# How to use getElementById with *ngIf?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, viewchild

I'm trying to select a div which has a *ngIf on it:

```
<div id="explanation" *ngIf="isCorrect(option.optionValue)">
```

which returns null when I use getElementById. If I remove ngIf it works fine, but I need to use the ngIf in my app. So how do I go about selecting the div?

EDIT: refactored code like this:

```
<div [hidden]="!isCorrect(option.optionValue)">
  <div id="explanation">
    Option {{ question.answer }} is correct because {{ question.explanation }}.
  </div>
</div>


ngAfterViewInit() {
  let itemFrom = document.getElementById('explanation');
  let itemTo = document.getElementById('question');
}

radioChange(answer) {
  this.question.selectedOption = answer;
  this.answer.emit(answer);

  this.moveExplanation(this.itemFrom, this.itemTo);
}

moveExplanation(from, to) {
  to.replaceWith(from);
}
```

question and explanation are now both logged, replaceWith works, just need to remove the original explanation from underneath the correct answer and each question's explanation should move into the question box and similarly remove the explanation from underneath the correct answer.

Comment: You don't. You use a [ViewChild](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild)

Comment: I'm using @ViewChild('explanation', {static: true}) 
  private explanation: ElementRef; but getting an undefined error when logging in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Is your condition respected ?

Comment: added ngAfterViewInit code above, explanation and question are both logged but the replaceWith isn't working

Comment: okay got replaceWith working, now need to remove the original explanation element from underneath the correct answer. Also need it to work for the following questions - each question's explanation should be displayed in the question box.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have access to your div with TypeScript, then you need to mark it with a Hashtag

```
<div id="explanation" *ngIf="isCorrect(explanation)" #explanation>
```

and add the name into the parameter you use, to pass the value!

or with

```
<div [(ngModel)]="option"></div
```

Comment: I added the hashtag and now trying to use @ViewChild('explanation', {static: false}) explanation: ElementRef;  Is this the correct way of using ViewChild? I need to move the explanation div where the question div is. Trying to use this code but the JS doesn't seem to work:moveExplanation() {
    // let itemFrom = document.getElementById('explanation');
    let itemTo = document.getElementById('question');
    // console.log(itemFrom);
    console.log(itemTo);
    
    const moveItems = function(from, to) {
      to.replaceWith(from);
    };

    moveItems(this.explanation, itemTo);

Comment: I did console.log(this.explanation) in ngAfterViewInit and it says it's undefined.

Comment: I think you can use the *ngIf directly! like *ngIf="option == true". Make sure that you switch the option (true/false) in your x.component.ts